# SQL Server insert into non duplicates

Tags: sql-server, insert

Table with objects:

```
create table objects(
    ID int identity primary key,
    name varchar(50) unique
)
```

Lets say that we have in a table records `a,b,c`.
Inserting new rows given with string example `'d,e,f,c,b,d'`, using a function changing CSV string to a table and returning it.

I need to insert everything from string example that is not already in objects table, it would be `d,e,f`. How can I do it? I was thinking about

```
insert into objects(names)
select distinct names from split('d,e,f,c,b,d')
EXCEPT
select names from objects
```

but I am sure that it has better sollution.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used `MERGE` and it works

```
merge objects
using (select distinct name from split(@string,',')) as s
on objects.name=s.name
when not matched then insert(name) values (split.name);
```